# Working with canvas in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, wpf, pointers, canvas, visual-studio-2013

I am fairly new to C# and Visual Studio 2013. I have a rather big project to do and I am not the only one working on it. We have multiple classes in it and mine is in charge of managing the canvas in the main window (the canvas can be of ShapeContainer type since I will mostly be drawing circles and lines). But the point is: If my class is trying to draw in its private methods, how should it know of the canvas' existence? Since the `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas` object is a child of the MainWindow and I initialize an instance of my class in the MainWindow I thought of giving my class a pointer to the canvas (as I would have done in C/C++), but `private System.Windows.Controls.Canvas * c;` gives me a *Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type* error. I thought this might not be the way to go and that's why I decided to ask you guys what the good practice is? How would you resolve it in your applications? 
Also if I have `Class A` that has a public property of type `B` and then in `B` I set `parent` property to `A`, how does that interact? One of those properties must be understood as a pointer otherwise we would have an infinite recursion of one class being inside another or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.
MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Chrum graph" Height="525" Width="525" MinHeight="250" MinWidth="250">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="VisualGraph" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#AAAAAA"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    Core core;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        core = new Core();
    }
```

Core.cs:

```
 public class Core
 {
      private IVisual visual;
 }
```

Visual.cs:

```
 public class Visual: IVisual
 {
       private void draw()
       {
           //this is where i want to use the canvas and draw in it
       }
 }
```

Comment: you don't use pointers in managed classes.  C# and C++ are not the same.  Why don't you describe what you are trying to do, aside from getting a pointer? what were you planning to do with the pointer (or the canvas)?

Comment: Also, you seem to be asking about the C# language here, Visual Studio is only an IDE, it doesn't change how you interact with objects or classes, so seems to be irrelevant here.

Comment: I want to draw in the canvas in private methods of my `Class Visual` which is a child of `Class Core` which is a child of `MainWindow`. The canvas i also a child of the `MainWindow`, but obviously the canvas is not visible in `Visual`.

Comment: actually, that isn't obvious, without any sort of code showing the relationship between these classes....

Comment: for example, if you have `Canvas theCanvas = new Canvas();`, and you want to use that in your class function, then you should be able to supply `theCanvas` as a parameter of your function, i.e. `Visual.SomeFunction(theCanvas);`.  Objects are always passed byRef in C#, so passing the object is very similar to passing a pointer in C++ would be.

Comment: And if I supply `theCanvas` from the comment above in the constructor of `Visual` as in `Visual v = Visual(theCanvas)`, will it also be passed by reference? That would mean any drawing I will do in my class function will appear in the MainWindow's canvas?

Comment: yes, any time you supply an object as a parameter to a function, it is passed byRef.  if you assign that object to a variable within your class, any function in your class which interacts with that variable will be interacting with that reference.

Comment: JohnSkeet has an excellent primer on the topic: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html

Comment: in the code you posted there, you would have to obtain the canvas object, supply that canvas object to `core`, and then supply that same object to the `visual` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cut the long story to short:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Chrum graph" Height="525" Width="525" MinHeight="250" MinWidth="250">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="VisualGraph" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#AAAAAA"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Core(VisualGraph).DrawSomething();
    }
```

Core:

```
class Core
{
    private Canvas innerCanvas;

    public Core(Canvas canvas)
    {
        this.innerCanvas = canvas;
    }

    public void DrawSomething()
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
        ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Red;
        ellipse.Width = 20;
        ellipse.Height = 20;
        ellipse.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty,20d);
        ellipse.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty,20d);
        this.innerCanvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
    }
}
```

[image]